# AWS Codepipeline with Codebuild FAILS in ap-southeast-2 WORKS in eu-west-1

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I execute the command

`aws cloudformation deploy`

on templates that create an `AWS::CodeBuild::Project` resource to be used in a `AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline` resource in the same template BUT I get the following error:

`CREATE_FAILED AWS::CloudFormation::Stack xyz Template format error: Unrecognized resource types: [AWS::CodeBuild::Project]`

If I switch regions to eu-west-1 which has had CodeBuild for a while now, templates work without any issues. I have run them many times.

I've posted to AWS Dev Forums but have not had any answers yet.

Any help that can be provided would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeBuild is not yet supported as a CloudFormation resource in that region.  We are working on adding it (I work on the CodeBuild team).

Comment: Thanks so much for confirming that. Is there a way I can be notified when it is fixed? Thanks.

Comment: Where is your AWS forum post? We can respond there when it's supported.

Comment: CloudFormation support has been updated; you should be able to create CodeBuild resources in ap-southwest-2 now